# How to create a C++ wrapper class for the following kind of C program?

Tags: c++, wrapper

I have created simple C++ wrapper classes before but my current problem is a bit confusing. I have a custom piece of hardware that can connected to a USB port and it gives out certain information depending on the configuration of the hardware based on which different event handlers are executed. It uses Ethernet-over-USB protocol. The C code on the PC side looks like this:

```
// Relevant headers

int Event1handler(){
  // Code to process event 1
}

void Event2handler(){
  // Code to process event 2
}

int main(void){
    // Code to setup calls to Event1handler() and Event2handler() using Open Sound Control methods
}
```

Now I am confused how to wrap a C++ class around the above code. In the C program, the event handlers are called automatically depending on what information is coming from the USB. How would I implement the event handlers as methods of a class that are automatically called depending on the information the hardware is sending? Can I put the contents of the main() function into the constructor of the class?

Edit: I do not need separate methods for the class. I just need to wrap the C program into a class. Putting all the event handlers into a single method is also fine (if its possible at all). I just need the data that each event handler receives.

Edit2: Here is what the actual event handlers and calls look like using OpenSoundControl:

```
// Relevant headers

int Event1handler(const char *path, const char *types, lo_arg **argv, int argc, void *data, void user_data){
  // Code to process event 1
}

void Event2handler(const char *path, const char *types, lo_arg **argv, int argc, void *data, void user_data){
  // Code to process event 2
}

int main(void){
    // Code to setup calls to Event1handler() and Event2handler() using Open Sound Control methods
    lo_server_thread st;
    // "if" means one integer and one float
    lo_server_thread_add_method(st, "/folder/data1", "if", Event1handler, NULL);
    lo_server_thread_add_method(st, "/folder/data2", "if", Event2handler, NULL);
}
```

Comment: I don't know Open Sound Control at all, but many C-based callback systems (GUI's especially) can be wrapped in a class. The callback functions are static member functions. These callbacks usually accept a pointer to user defined data. When you set up the callback in the object's constructor, you would pass `this` as that data. The callback would convert the pointer back to the class type then call a member function to do the actual work, passing any extra data that was given to the callback. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I feel its quite relevant. I will just add a little bit more code to my post so that you can see how OpenSoundControl works and if you think your idea is applicable, please do post some sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a class and put the code inside, for example in your `.h` file:

```
class EventWrapper
{
public:
   EventWrapper();
   static int Event1Handler();
   static void Event2Handler();
}
```

Then in your `.cpp` file:

```
#include "EventWrapper.h"
// Include relevant headers for your USB device

EventWrapper::EventWrapper()
{
   // Code to setup calls to Event1handler() and Event2handler()
   // using Open Sound Control methods.
}

int EventWrapper::Event1Handler()
{
   // Code to process event 1
}

void EventWrapper::Event2Handler()
{
   // Code to process event 2
}
```

Without knowing all of the details of your program you may have to play around with what is static and how you want to handle it.

Comment: Thanks. I imagined it would be like what you have posted but could you look at my second edit to see the Open Sound Control related lines? If the hardware is sending out data for Event1, will the EventWrapper::Event1Handler() be automatically called? That's whats confusing me. Also please see some additional code that I posted.

Comment: Another question related to my first one. It may be very trivial but..how do I call the static member functions without knowing what data will be sent to through the USB?

Comment: These two static member functions should automatically be called from the USB driver code. You are telling the USB driver code to call these when it needs to so put your processing code in these two functions.

Comment: You shouldn't be calling these static member functions. The USB driver code is what should be calling these functions (or the Open Sound Control). The point of a callback function is it sits there and does nothing until some event, outside of your code, calls the function and you process what is needed. I.e. the USB/OpenSound will process something and once it has data to report to you it will call those two static functions. You don't call the static functions yourself, you simply add code to them to process the result from USB/OpenSound.

Comment: Thanks so much. That makes sense.